# MCMC uncertainties vanish

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, uncertainty

I'm trying to fit a signal modelled by a Lorentzian ($f(x) = \frac{\text{Amplitude}}{1 + 4((x-\text{center})/\text{width}^2)}$), thus I have 3 parameters : **Amplitude, Central frequency** and **width**. I use **uniform priors** for Amplitude and Central frequency ($\frac{1}{\theta_{\max} - \theta_{\min}}$), and **Jeffreys prior** for the width ($\frac{1}{\theta \ln(\theta_{\max}/\theta_{\min})}$).

The resulting fit seem to work fine, but the **uncertainties vanish**, which is problematic. I calculate the uncertainties by taking the **16th, 50th and 84th percentiles** to get a σ deviation (50th - 16th and 84th - 50th) on both sides of the median, after discarding the burn-in steps.

Problem is, after the burn-in steps, the walkers are all converged pretty much to the same value, meaning the standard deviation of their distribution vanishes, and so do my uncertainties :
$$
\mathrm{{Amplitude}} = 3242_{-23}^{15}, \mathrm{{Central frequency}} = 112.613_{0.000}^{0.000}, \mathrm{{Width\,1}} = 0.116_{0.000}^{0.000} 
$$
This is a plot of the evolution of the walker's positions in time, showing convergence of the walkers :
[image: Walker plot]

This is the resulting corner plot, made by discarding the first 400 steps (burn-in) :
[image: Corner plot]

This is the signal to be fitter with the resulting lorentzian whose parameters were estimated via the MCMC :

[image: Lorentzian fit]

Any idea why the uncertainties I compute vanish ? If all the  walkers finish on the same position in parameter-space, the resulting distribution would be a single peak and have a width of basically 0. How do I reconcile this with the fact that surely, the uncertainty of my fit should not be 0, given my signal is not a perfect lorentzian ?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! Thank you for editing your question. It is now reopened, and I hope you get helpful answers.